Using Playwright for e2e testing of an Electron app launches correctly, but await electron.launch is never resolved
We are using playwright to write end to end tests for our electron application. We are seeing an issue intermittently when calling const electronApp = await electron.launch(launchOptions);. Our application will launch and be fully interactable but the await will never resolve and will eventually time out.
The problem seems like this issue but we only see the issue seemingly randomly. The fuse they mention is turned on so that solution is not the issue.
We are currently using Playwright 1.29.2. When we update to any version later than this the issue seems to happen more often, but the tests still pass sometimes.
We get to sendMessageToServer in channelOwner.js sending prop='launch' this promise is never resolved.
Checked the nodeCliInspect fuse to make sure it's enabled.
Increased timeout to make sure it wasn't just taking a little longer.
Tried running with the playwright debugger but it is just blank as if it can't connect to the application.
